# Can some explain how modular arithmetic works

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Say I have a problem like 2^191 divided by 5, how can I solve this using only modular arithmetic?

Comment: Tell us what you know about modular arithmetic and how you got started. Can you solve the problem for a few smaller exponents? Give it a try, report by editing your question. Then maybe we can help instead of downvoting.

Comment: It helps to note that $2^4\equiv 1 \pmod 5$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: and why 2^4≡1(mod5) do you convert to binary form to know that?

Comment: Just write it down!  $2^4=16$ and $16=15+1$.

Comment: ok thanks but why 15+1, why not 14+2?

Comment: @Simon We want $\mod 5$, not $\mod 14$ or $\mod 7$.

Comment: I think you need to review the basic definitions.  I'm sure whatever text you are using goes over these things.

Comment: so does 15 represent the time occurring of 5? wtch is 3 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here note that $2^4\equiv 1 \pmod 5 \implies (2^4)^{47} \equiv 1^{47} \pmod 5 \implies (2^4)^{47} \times 2^3 \equiv 1^{47} \times 8 \pmod 5 \\ \implies 2^{191} \equiv 3\pmod 5. $

$2^4 = 16 = 15+1$.

Comment: thanks but how did you get 2^4 to =1?

Comment: @Simon $16 \equiv 1 \pmod {5}$.

Comment: @Simon Have your learned yet about the *order* of an invertible element $a$ mod $n,\,$ i.e. the least natural number $k$ such that $\,a^{\large k}\equiv 1\pmod n\,?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque no, Im at the very begning at this